# How do I determine where the maximum air velocity around an object is?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, classical-mechanics

I have a freestream of air directed at an object. Is there a way to find where the maximum air velcoty occurs with only having initial air speed and static pressure at the object?

Comment: Experimental, emperical or simulation way?

Comment: Empirical. I have the velocity of the air stream approaching and object equipped with static pressure holes on its surface, and I'm given the minimum gauge pressure the holes read. Is this the stagnation pressure?
I was able to apply Bernoulli's principle and I found a velocity which was correct but I'm not sure why it's deemed to be the MAXIMUM velocity